# IE is inconsistently rendering JavaScript divs

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, html

I'm trying to display a bunch of divs that are rendered to look like vertical and horizontal lines.  While the code technically works, it doesn't work consistently.  On the first page load, only one line may show, and on the next an entirely different one may show, or they'll all show.  I'm testing this on IE8 and IE9 with the same problem, and am a bit lost at this point.

I'm using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "linesCode", script, false);` to register the script, but it does the same thing using the old `RegisterStartupScript(key, string)` method.

Code that is being registered, pulled from the browsers' "View Source":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        drawLineVertical('MainContent_1_ClauseRowDefaultTable', 'MainContent_3_AddRowTable', 2, 30);
        drawLineHorizontal('MainContent_1_ClauseRowDefaultTable', 'MainContent_2_ConditionRowTable', 2, 40);
        drawLineHorizontal('MainContent_1_ClauseRowDefaultTable', 'MainContent_3_AddRowTable', 2, 30);
    });
</script>
```

Code that is being processed (most of this was found in an old blog post):

```
function drawLineVertical(id1, id2, wid, offset) {
    var obj1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    var obj2 = document.getElementById(id2);

    var obj1Pos = GetCoordinates(obj1);
    var obj2Pos = GetCoordinates(obj2);

    var id = 'line_' + new Date().getTime();
    var line = "<div id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"line\"></div>";
    $('body').append(line);
    $('#' + id).css({
        left: obj1Pos.x,
        top: obj1Pos.y,
        height: ((obj2Pos.y - obj1Pos.y) + offset),
        width: wid,
        position: 'absolute',
        background: '#c2c5d1',
        backgroundcolor: '#c2c5d1'
    });
}

function drawLineHorizontal(id1, id2, h, offset) {
    var obj1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    var obj2 = document.getElementById(id2);

    var obj1Pos = GetCoordinates(obj1);
    var obj2Pos = GetCoordinates(obj2);

    var id = 'line_' + new Date().getTime();
    var line = "<div id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"line\"></div>";
    $('body').append(line);
    $('#' + id).css({
        left: obj1Pos.x,
        top: (obj2Pos.y + offset),
        height: h,
        width: obj2Pos.x - obj1Pos.x,
        position: 'absolute',
        background: '#c2c5d1',
        backgroundcolor: '#c2c5d1'
    });
}

function GetCoordinates(obj) {
    var pos = {};
    pos.x = obj.offsetLeft;
    pos.y = obj.offsetTop;
    while (obj.offsetParent) {
        pos.x = pos.x + obj.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
        pos.y = pos.y + obj.offsetParent.offsetTop;
        if (obj == document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried window.onload instead of $(document).ready ?

Comment: @srosh Good idea, but I just tried it with no luck.

Comment: If this takes < 1 ms, then you will duplicate your element IDs.

Comment: @Diodeus I tried separating each line draw with its own setTimeout() to see if that was the problem, still has the same issue though.  Had no idea that the speed of execution could affect it, very valuable info.

Comment: Why not just use a counter?

Comment: counter is a good idea, or just random numbers. but I was wondering is this an IE issue or it's the same behavior in other browsers?

Comment: Replaced the date with a random integer and got the same result. Tried it on Chrome as well with the same result.  However, when I opened it in IE9 and switched the compatibility mode to IE8 it worked perfectly every time.  Seems odd that the IE8 compatibility mode works, while actual IE8 does not.